# Restart Kestrel in Memory

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I have an instance of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHost` created using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()`.

This may be a stupid question but I can't seem to find a straightforward way to call `IWebHost.StopAsync()` then `IWebHost.StartAsync()` to basically restart the server in memory without a full process restart.

I keep getting **`System.InvalidOperationException: Server has already started.`**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so what do you mean by *restart* exactly? is there crietria whether restart is successful or not? can a app kill itself and restart, cleanly?

Comment: No. I don't want to kill the app, I want to stop Kestrel and start it again. And Yes, I have connected clients that I can tell whether the server disconnected and connected again.

Comment: then what's the bad thing of restarting the process?

Comment: The bad thing is that the process is a unit testing process, so killing it basically breaks the test.

Comment: can you explain why you need *restart* during unit test? a unit test even shouldn't start  a service.

Comment: There is some state that I want to make sure that it is preserved between disconnects between the client and the server. So, I want to make sure that restarting Kestrel does not affect this state.

Comment: i think it belongs to system test scope.

Comment: I don't want to go into a practices discussion. I simply know there is a StopAsync and StartAsync methods which per the documentation should do what their names indicate. So, why aren't they doing that and how to make them do what they should do?

Comment: a man can born, and can die. does this imply he can rebirth?

Comment: Do you have a reference for this relevant to Kestrel? Something .NET Documentation clearly says.

Comment: You cannot restart the host, you can create a new one.